# A Hundred Squares!

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, grid

#### Back to basics...

As a teacher at the local primary (grade?) school, you need a way to teach your class their times tables. At your disposal, you have hundred squares and a load of red pens. You need to also be able to show your class the correct answers quickly.

Now, you're clever enough to write a program that can do times tables, but can you draw them on a hundred square?

## The challenge

Output a hundred square to stdout or equivalent using [ansi-escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to shade in numbers which are multiples of the input.

- Output a 10x10 grid containing the numbers 1-100.

  - It doesn't matter the alignment of 2 digit numbers in each box as long as it's consistant
  - For 1 digit numbers, you may pad to 2 digits and use the same formatting as 2 digit numbers or centered in the middle of the box.
- If the number in the box is a multiple of the input, colour the entire box red.

  - This means the whole box, not just the number part

For example, given the input `3`, print the given hundred square

[image: hundred square 3]

**This is code golf so the shortest answer in bytes wins!**

Comment: Can we print 01 instead of 1. 02 for 2, etc etc

Comment: So I can't use `<table>`, for example?

Comment: Does the colour of the numbers matter? Can it be `white` or `grey`?

Comment: @Keatinge I haven't decided yet - I'm veering towards yes @nicael no, it has to be using ansi-escapes or answers wouldn't be on the same playing field, @BassdropCumberwubwubwub you may use different colours but unless you're using `curses` it shouldn't matter - red is short anyway.

Comment: @Keatinge yes you may use padding - but only with zeros and one one digit numbers only

Comment: ANSI codes aren't supported by windows,,,

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg I haven't tried it but https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon - I've got putty on my windows box

Comment: @muddyfish It don't compile on my machine

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg try mobaXterm - I've just tried it and and it works locally with ansi

Comment: My reference golfed python solution is about 272 bytes - It could easily be beasten though with minimal optimisation

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg Doesn't mean the question should be closed or is a bad challenge ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Insane I have never sayed that this is a bad challenge

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg I know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Python 2, 166 bytes

```
R=range;n=input()
for y in R(21):print''.join('♥[%dm%s♥[m'%(any(5>x-k%10*4>-1<y-k/10*2<3for k in R(n-1,100,n))*41,('+---|%2d '%(x/4+y*5-4))[y%2*4+x%4])for x in R(41))
```

Replace `♥` by octal `033` (the ANSI escape character).

[image]

### Explanation

We treat the output as a `41×21` grid, and directly compute the character and color at each point.

That is, the structure of the code is:

```
n = input()
for y in range(21):
    print ''.join(F(x, y) for x in range(41))
```

for some function `F`.

The result of `F` is always of the following form:

> - An ANSI [*Control Sequence Introducer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Sequence_elements) (`\33[`).
> - An [SGR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics): `0m` for reset, or `41m` for red background.
> - A single character. (`+`, `-`, `|`, space, or digit)
> - An SGR reset sequence (`\33[m`).

We use the format string `'\33[%dm%s\33[m'`, where the first `%d` is either 0 or 41, and the `%s` is the character we wish to print.

---

For the **color**, we have the following formula:

```
any(5>x-k%10*4>-1<y-k/10*2<3for k in R(n-1,100,n))*41
```

I’m not going to fully explain this, but it basically loops over all rectangles that should be colored red, and checks if `(x, y)` is inside any of them.

Note the use of operator chaining: I rewrote `-1<A<5 and -1<B<3` into `5>A>-1<B<3`.

---

For the **character**, we have the following formula:

```
('+---|%2d '%(x/4+y*5-4))[y%2*4+x%4]
```

If `y % 2 == 0` then for `x = 0, 1, …` this will generate `+---+---+---…`

If `y % 2 == 1` then for `x = 0, 1, …` this will generate `| p |p+1|p+2…`

Comment: One of these days, there's going to be a challenge where you actually need to use a literal ♥ in the code, and everybody will be confused ;)

Comment: Would love to see an explanation.

Comment: @shaunakde I wrote something up (but saved some bytes in the process, so maybe it also got slightly harder to follow… ^^)

Comment: @Lynn - Here I thought I had you beat with my Julia code, and you go and tweak just enough to beat me by 1.

Comment: @Lynn Thank you so much for taking the time and energy to explain this code. I am very thankful for this explanation. It helped me learn a lot!

Comment: You’re very welcome! :)

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>219</s> <s>182</s> <s>169</s> 167 bytes

```julia
!n=(~j=j%n<1;k(v=j->"---",c=+,s="$c\e[m";l=~)=println([(l(j)?"\e[;;41m$c":s)v(j)for j=10i+(1:10)]...,s);i=0;k();for i=0:9 k(j->lpad(j,3),|);k(l=j->~j|~(j+10(i<9)))end)
```

Used like this: `!7`

Ungolfed:

```julia
function !(n::Integer)
     for j=(1:10)     #This loop generates the top of the box
       if (j%n==0)
         print("\e[;;41m+---") #"\e[;;41m" is the ANSI escape code
                               #for red background colour in Julia
       else
         print("+\e[m---")     #"\e[m" resets to original colours
       end
     end
     println("+\e[m")
     for i=0:9
       for j=10i+(1:10)  #This loop generates the rows with the numbers
         if (j%n==0)
           print("\e[;;41m|",lpad(j,3))
         else
           print("|\e[m",lpad(j,3))
         end
       end
       println("|\e[m")
       for j=10i+(1:10)  #This loop generates the other rows
         if (j%n==0)||((j+10)%n==0&&i<9)
           print("\e[;;41m+---")
         else
           print("+\e[m---")
         end
       end
       println("+\e[m")
     end
   end
```

Note that this is *very* ungolfed, for maximal readability.

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML + Javascript, 379

HTML:

```
<input id=a value=3><pre id=z>
```

Javascript:

```
for(i=0,s=`\n|`,o='+';i++<109;x=i<10?` ${i} `:i-100?' '+i:i,s+=x+'|',o+=x='---+',i%10||(o+=s+'\n+',s=`\n|`));z.innerHTML=[...o+x].map((x,i)=>`<span id=i${i}>${x}</span>`).join``;f=m=>window['i'+m].style.background='red';for(j=k=+a.value;j<=100;j+=k){p=(j/10|0)*84+((m=j%10)?(m-1)*4:-48);'000102030442434445468485868788'.match(/../g).map(x=>f(+x+p))}
```

[jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jhzusj3j/3/)